# Custom Tizen push message

Tags: web-applications, push-notification, push, tizen

I am developing the Tizen web application and I used the Tizen push API.
I successfully received the alert message from the Tizen push server, but how would like to custom the push message.
I used the code below

```
"badgeOption=INCREASE&badgeNumber=1&action=ALERT&alertMessage=Hi"
```

How could I custom the push message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've prepared two working scenarios with push server and Galaxy Watch by following below points.

**Handling push message inside running web application**

1. I've created very simple application and applied these [prerequisites](https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/messaging/push/#prerequisites)
2. Inside my application I've created directory shared/res with test.jpg file (my test icon for this scenario)
3. I've prepared web-based code for sending push notifications to my testing device (please notice the message I've used to add custom icon):

```
function sendMessage(registeredId, msg) {
    if (registeredId == undefined || msg == undefined || msg == "") {
        console.err("error registering application!");
        return;
    }
    var appId = "<<<your application package id>>>";
    var sec = "<<<your application's push server secret code>>>";

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var data = {
        "regID": registeredId,
        "requestID": "000001",
        "message": "action=ALERT&imageTypeIcon=test.jpg&alertMessage="+msg
    };

    var idToUrlMap = {
        "00": "https://useast.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "02": "https://apsoutheast.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "03": "https://euwest.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "04": "https://apnortheast.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "05": "https://apkorea.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "06": "https://apchina.push.samsungosp.com.cn:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "50": "https://useast.gateway.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "52": "https://apsoutheast.gateway.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "53": "https://euwest.gateway.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "54": "https://apnortheast.gateway.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "55": "https://apkorea.gateway.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "56": "https://apchina.gateway.push.samsungosp.com.cn:8090/spp/pns/api/push"
    };

    var url = idToUrlMap[registeredId.substring(0,2)];
    request.open("POST", url, true);

    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.setRequestHeader("appID", appId);
    request.setRequestHeader("appSecret", sec);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
            console.log("Push Success");
        }
    };
    request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

4. I've started my application in debug mode, and using below code I registered application for push notifications and send message:

```
    function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("The following error occurred: " + response.name);
    }

    function registerSuccessCallback(id) {
        console.log("Registration succeeded with id: " + id);
        sendMessage(id, message || "Test application message")
    }

    function stateChangeCallback(state) {
        console.log("The state is changed to: " + state);

        if (state == "UNREGISTERED") {
            tizen.push.register(registerSuccessCallback, errorCallback);
        } else {
            var id = tizen.push.getRegistrationId();
            sendMessage(id, message || "Test application message")
        }
    }

    function notificationCallback(notification) {
        console.log("A notification arrives: " + JSON.stringify(notification));
    }

    /* Connects to push service. */
    tizen.push.connect(stateChangeCallback, notificationCallback, errorCallback);
```

5. After a while, notificationCallback raises and shows console log with received data:

*A notification arrives: {"alertMessage":"Test application message","appData":"","date":"2021-01-19T10:23:11.000Z","message":"action=ALERT&imageTypeIcon=test.jpg&alertMessage=Test application message","requestId":"000001","sender":"","sessionInfo":""}*

6. This is the end of basic scenario - in this case you need to handle message inside your application.

**Background scenario - push message handled automatically by service**

Second scenario is when the application is in background and push message is handled automatically by push service. Points 1-3 are the same. After that you need to move your application into background and continue with point 4.
After a while customized notification with test.jpg icon should be shown as a system notification.

Answer (score 1):

Possible contents of push message are described in detail here https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/messaging/push-server/
The guide unfortunately is for native application, however most of it should easily apply to all profiles.

If you want to customize the looks of your push messages by adding icon, changing sound or adding quick actions it's described in Decorating Push Notifications section.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I applied the code described in the guide, but it is not working in the web application. Does it mean that I have to switch my application to a native application?

Comment: If you are referring to the C code with app_control function, you have to recreate said function using webapi. `!strcmp(a,b)` can be replaced by `a!=b` and app_control_get_extra_data() should be replaced by retrieving key,value pair form appcontorl.data[] https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/mobile/tizen/application.html#ApplicationControlData. You'll likely need to enable receiving app control requests as describend in this guide https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/app-management/app-controls/#receiving-and-replying-to-application-control-requests

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That link helped me a lot. But is there any way to add an icon or image to push notification messages in the web application?

Comment: Hi, could you please specify what does it mean, that 'it is not working in the web application'? In this https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/guides/messaging/push/#receiving-push-notifications section you have the description of desired behaviour depending of Web application state: when application is closed, the default behaviour should be same as for native, when application is up, you could handle messages in https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/device_api/mobile/tizen/push.html#PushNotificationCallback

Comment: I'm not sure if I remember correctly from working with push notifications. Notification in quickpanel was created automatically, if so you should put your image in `shared/res/` folder and add `&imageTypeIcon=icon.png&` to the message field in your push notification.

Comment: So, I am developing a wearable web application. I strictly followed https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/messaging/push-server/, but it is for the native application. It seems that it is not working in the web application. Or am I doing something wrong? I also tried &imageTypeIcon=icon.png& with storing the icon image under shared/res/ folder, but it is not working. The notification only shows the alert message. Please help...